# How to git difftool after a commit

Tags: git

I have committed some work, done a pull, committed the merge but not pushed yet. I'd like to use `difftool *` to compare my local changes (ideally not any work I have pulled).

I can't do `git difftool *` because I have committed my work.

I'd prefer not to have to use commit IDs, i'd rather just diff between what I have and what the remote has.

What's the simplest way to use `difftool *` in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you're on the branch that has upstream set so it's just enough to do:

```
git difftool @{upstream}
```

`@{upstream}` is described in [`man gitrevisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions):

```
   <branchname>@{upstream}, e.g. master@{upstream}, @{u}

       The suffix @{upstream} to a branchname (short form
       <branchname>@{u}) refers to the branch that the branch
       specified by branchname is set to build on top of
       (configured with branch.<name>.remote and
       branch.<name>.merge). A missing branchname defaults to the
       current one.
```

Comment: So far git difftool  master origin/master seems to work?

Comment: No need to type branch names if you're on master - type `@{upstream}` literally. It's a Git built-in alias.

Comment: Will this only show all my un-pushed commits on that branch, or only since the last one? Is there a way to see the difference for all my un-pushed commits?

Answer (score -1):

To see the diff for a particular COMMIT hash:

git diff COMMIT~ COMMIT will show you the difference between that COMMIT's ancestor and the COMMIT. See the man pages for git diff ( http://jk.gs/git-diff.html ) for details about the command and gitrevisions ( http://jk.gs/gitrevisions.html )  about the ~ notation and its friends.

Alternatively, git show COMMIT will do something very similar. (The commit's data, including its diff - but not for merge commits.) See git here: http://jk.gs/git-show.html